# Fibonacci sequence using For Loop

Tags: python, fibonacci

This qustion is to Write a program that outputs the nth Fibonacci number.

I dont understand why do we need n-1 in the range()

```
def fib_linear(n: int) -> int:
    if n <= 1:  # first fibonacci number is 1 
        return n
 
    previousFib = 0
    currentFib = 1
 
    for i in range(n - 1):  
        newFib = previousFib + currentFib
        previousFib = currentFib
        currentFib = newFib
 
    return currentFib
```

Comment: You have already the first number before the loop so you need one less.

Comment: you have 0th, 1st fib no already, for subsequent fib no you are using for loop and so with this loop exceute n-2 times and will give nth fib no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause you wanna output n-th fibonacci number. If you put "n" instead of "n-1". Then you'll get n+1-th fibonacci number.